# UIScrollView won't scroll, delegate methods never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have several `UILabel` inside the child view of a `UIScrollView`. I believe I've set it up exactly like the functioning `UIScrollView` I have in another view controller, only this one won't scroll. The `contentSize` is set to **larger** than the scrollview `frame` size and scrollview `delegate` is set to `self`. The views are wired up in Interface Builder and the `UIScrollview` has scrolling enabled, bounces, user interaction and multiple touch enabled. The child `UIView` also has user interaction enabled. Here is my code:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CreditsViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "CreditsViewController.h"

@interface CreditsViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

@end

@implementation CreditsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    _scrollView.contentSize = _contentView.frame.size;
    NSLog(@"scrollview frame size, contentview frame size: %f x %f, %f x %f", _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height, _contentView.frame.size.width, _contentView.frame.size.height);
}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
NSLog(@"in scrollViewWillBeginDragging");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"in scrollViewDidScroll");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

I get *scrollview frame size, contentview frame size: 240.000000 x 128.000000, 320.000000 x 568.000000* as the log printout but I never get the statements from the delegate methods. The scrollview is the only child of the view controller so it should be receiving the touch events when I try to scroll. What's going on?

Comment: Check the outlet connection

Comment: how big is the contentSize? it would only scroll if the content size is larger than the scrollview size

Comment: The contentSize is 320x568, which is larger than the scrollview frame size (240x128).

Comment: Check if "User interaction enabled" is checked in your XIB

Comment: Yes, the outlets are correct and user interaction enabled is checked.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to implement viewForZoomingInScrollView: and return your _contentView.

Comment: I don't want users to be able to zoom, so actually I would return nil, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: For panning without zooming set mininumScrollViewScale and maximumZoomScale = 1. I think the downvote is because if the scroll view and content view are set up correctly in IB then you don't need viewForZoomingInScrollView. This delegate method is required if you are building your UI in code, but don't return nil from it. You do need to set your contentSize to be larger than the visible area of the scrollView as suggested by Fonix. That should do it.

Comment: Do you have constraints on your content view?

Comment: No constraints. I've built my UI in IB and only added the delegate to be able to see if the methods were being called at all to try to figure out why it's not working.